# Как увеличить скорость поиска на сайте?

Tags: php, sql

Как увеличить скорость формы поиска на сайте ? На данный момент использую в запросе sql "like "искомый текст" ". База большая и нужно искать по описанию всех страниц, т.е. каждая страница имеет текст ~ 2000 символов , и количество страниц 150 000. Наблюдается медленный поиск который отрабатывает около 10 и более секунд. Как можно увеличить скорость запроса sql.? Либо это зависит только от скорости сервера?

Comment: а Вы каждый раз по базе делаете поиск с помощью like? это на любой базе будет не быстро. Пробовали использовать что то вида  Sphinx или Apache Solr?

Comment: ...или ElasticSearch? Или, на худой конец, возможности полнотекстового поиска MySQL/PostgreSQL?

Comment: @KoVadim , да каждый раз использую только like . База MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Если mysql и база myisam то https://habrahabr.ru/post/40218/
Если postgreSQL то http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/fts_pgsql_intro.html

Так же есть ElasticSearch и Sphinx, но эти штуки для более сложных вещей, чем полнотекстовый поиск по 1 полю.

Comment: Не знаю как mysql, но postgres может многотекстово искать по многим полям. И даже можно назначать полям разный вес.

Comment: @hardworm , а что для MySQL есть, какой способ ?

Comment: так написал же какой.  Читай и пользуй